# Mysql: Display values of column below another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am really stuck in this. I have tried union, by preparing a an executable statement. I am very well aware that SQL is not a language meant for such type of tasks, but as of now, the objective is to create a prototype. The actual technical implementations would happen later.

I will explain my requirements.

There is a temporary table, in which I am storing name, project and features related to that project. The columns store rows as:

Sample Data:

```
   project, Tracker, resource_name, Total_Hours, date, project_counts, 

   'Slim', 'Feature', 'babu.balakrishnan', '39', '2016-10-22', '20'
   'Slim', 'Feature', 'prasenjit.ghosh',  '1.5', '2016-10-22', '2'
   'Slim', 'Feature', 'shamim.akhtar',    '3',   '2016-10-22', '2'
   'Slim', 'Support', 'babu.balakrishnan', NULL, '2016-10-22', '1'
   'Slim', 'Support', 'shamim.akhtar',     '3',  '2016-10-22', '2'
```

I want output to be displayed in this manner:

```
   babu.balakrishnan    Slim     2016-10-22    
                       Feature      20                        
                       Support      1             


      prasenjit.ghosh   Slim                                   
                        Feature     3
```

I know how to display name of developer, name of project and date in one row, but I am not able to figure out how shall I proceed to display the status of project below the project name. Also, this is for only one developer. I need to repeat this for all the projects, with which a developer is associated and then, also, for other developers too.

```
       SELECT
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
       CONCAT(
       'CASE WHEN date = ''',
       date,
       ''' then project_counts end AS `', date, '`' )
       ORDER BY date ) INTO @sql
       FROM finance_dashboard.resource_utilization_data;

       SELECT
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
       CONCAT(
       'CASE WHEN project = ''', 
       project,
       ''' then Tracker end AS `', ' ' , '`' )
       ORDER BY date ) INTO @sql2
       FROM finance_dashboard.resource_utilization_data;

       SET @sql = CONCAT('select distinct resource_name, project        
       ,',@sql, ' from finance_dashboard.resource_utilization_data 
       union
       select '''' ,', @sql2, '," " FROM        
       finance_dashboard.resource_utilization_data group by 
       Tracker');
```

The output which I am getting is:

```
       'babu.balakrishnan',  'Slim', '20'
       'prasenjit.ghosh',    'Slim', '2'
       'shamim.akhtar',      'Slim', '2'
       'babu.balakrishnan',  'Slim', '1'
                         '', 'Feature', ' '
```

I want Feature, Support or whatever status for that developer, to appear below slim, for respective developers.

Is this possible at query level? I know, aggregate function has to be used.

Also, is it possible to bind variables dyamically, so that the value of particular row gets written below the column?

Thanks

Comment: Are the number of dates fixed, or are they variable?  At first glance, I would say that this is something which might best be handled in your app layer (PHP?).

Comment: Yes. Dates are not an issue. The SQL would be run for start date and end date. The only thing which I need to show is the data, which is getting stored in a summary table. Unfortunately, as of now, any other programming language is not being recommended to use.

Comment: Your sample data and output do not line up nicely, at least it not clear how to arrive at it.  Please give a reproducible example.

Comment: sql isn't a programming language. Surely you are not asking the end user to copy paste a query to see this result?? How is it being displayed?

Comment: This is at a POC level actually. We are creating a prototype to display result in the manner which I have put above. We would export this to CSV, as now. These data has to be captured into dashboard, but that's at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db=new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

$result=$db->query("select date,project_id,name ... from tableName");

while(list($date,$project_id,$name)=$result->fetch_row()){
   echo "<div class='record'>";
      echo "<div class='field'><strong>Date:</strong> $date</div>";
      echo "<div class='field'><strong>Project:</strong> $project_id</div>";
      echo "<div class='field'><strong>Name:</strong> $name</div>";
   echo "</div>";

 }
```